# Единая кнопка "Плей/Пауза" в Adobe Animate в HTML5 canvas

Tags: html5, canvas, animate, adobe

Подскажите как сделать единую кнопку "плей/пауза" в Adobe Animate в HTML5 canvas ?

Я новичок в Animate и очень плохо разбираюсь в коде. В снипетах нашел код для отдельно кнопки "плей" и отдельно для кнопки "пауза".

Как сделать что нажав на кнопку плей - анимация начинала двигаться а вместо кнопкий "плей" уже показвалась кнопка "пауза"?

Comment: Разобрался как сделать? мне тоже нужно, не могу найти как(((

Comment: Алгоритм примерно такой: надо рисовать кнопки одна над другой, кнопка пауза по дефолту скрыта, при нажатии на кнопку плей кнопка плей скрывается, а кнопка пауза показывается, при нажатии на кнопку пауза, кнопка пауза скрывается, а кнопка плей показывается.